# How to add button in HeaderSpan of SmartGWT

Tags: smartgwt

I want to add a button to the HeaderSpan of ListGrid in SmartGWT. I tried using the 'HeaderSpan.setAttribute((String property, Object value)) method but it did not work. Below is the example I tried with:-

```
ListGrid countryGrid = new ListGrid();
HeaderSpan ident = new HeaderSpan("Identification", new String[]{"countryCode", "countryName"});
ident.setAttribute("control", new Button("Test"));
countryGrid.setHeaderSpans(ident);
countryGrid.draw();
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the way to add button to a HeaderSpan. Below is the code (Have omitted import statements for brevity):-

```
public class AdvancedListGrid extends ListGrid {
    public void setHeaderSpanButtons() {
        this.getAttribute("headerSpans");

        NodeList<Element> list = this.getElement().getElementsByTagName("td");
        int length = list.getLength();
        for(int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            Element element = list.getItem(index);

            if(element.getInnerHTML().toString().equals("Identification")) {
                element.setInnerHTML(null);
                element.insertFirst(createHeaderSpanContents());
            }
        }
    }

    private Element createHeaderSpanContents() {
        HLayout hLayout = new HLayout();
        Button button = new Button("+");
        button.setHeight(20);
        button.setWidth(20);
        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                SC.say("Why did you click me?");
            }});

        Label title = new Label("Test Title");
        title.setWidth(70);
        title.setHeight(20);

        hLayout.addMember(button);
        hLayout.addMember(new LayoutSpacer());
        hLayout.addMember(title);

        return hLayout.getElement();
    }
}
```

The client class will call the AdvancedListGrid.setHeaderSpanButtons() method to add buttons to the header span. Of course you can customize the method to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm testing it, as I need to put a Calendar in a HeaderSpan. Thanks for sharing your idea, it's of great help, although it took a while to set the correct imports.

*A note* : the setHeaderSpanButtons() method will only work if the datasource of the ListGrid is set. If it's not, no header at all is shown.

*An improvement* : you can add a break in the loop, no need to loop the whole NodeList:

```
if(element.getInnerHTML().toString().equals("Identification")) {
            element.setInnerHTML(null);
            element.insertFirst(createHeaderSpanContents());
            break;
        }
```

*A question* : what is the purpose of this line:

```
this.getAttribute("headerSpans");
```

*And finally*, it doesn't work for me - the span stays always as text "Identification". Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Break is a good idea. `this.getAttribute()` is not needed. My suggestion would be to do `element.setInnerHTML(calendarObject.getInnerHTML());` instead of setting `innerHTML` to `null`. Also, call the main methods from `onDraw()` method. One more extra thing that I am doing is removing all the child nodes by calling `DOMUtils.removeAllChildNodes()` method. Have pasted detail code in my 2nd answer. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you test it on IE? I tested in FF and it works fine, but I have problems when clicking around my app in IE. As far as I read, it is due to the mix of GWT and SmartGWT. So I guess it's better to use a ToolStrip like in this example: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_appearance_preferences

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Node;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.NodeList;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.DrawEvent;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.DrawHandler;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGrid;

public class AdvancedListGrid extends ListGrid {
    public AdvancedListGrid() {

        // Create the HeaderSpan with title "Identification"

        addDrawHandler(new DrawHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onDraw(DrawEvent event) {
                insertCalendar();
            }});
    }

    public void insertCalendar() {
        for(Element element : DOMUtils.getElementsByTagName("td")) {

            if(element.getInnerHTML().equals("Identification")) {
                createCalendar(element);

            }
        }
    }

    public void createCalendar(Element element) {
        DOMUtils.removeAllChildNodes(element);

        // Create the SmartGWT calendar object. Say the object cal.

        element.setInnerHTML(cal.getInnerHTML());
    }
}

class DOMUtils {
    public static void removeAllChildNodes(Element element) {
        NodeList<Node> childList = element.getChildNodes();
        for(int childIndex = 0; childIndex < childList.getLength(); childIndex++) {
            element.removeChild(childList.getItem(childIndex));
        }
    }

    public static Element[] getElementsByTagName(String tagName)
    {
        JavaScriptObject elements = getElementsByTagNameInternal(tagName);
        int length = getArrayLength(elements);
        Element[] result = new Element[length];
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = getArrayElement(elements, i);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static native JavaScriptObject getElementsByTagNameInternal(String tagName)/*-{
    return $doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
  }-*/;

    private static native int getArrayLength(JavaScriptObject array)/*-{
    return array.length;
  }-*/;

    private static native Element getArrayElement(JavaScriptObject array, int position)/*-{
    return (position>=0 && position<array.length?array[position]:null);
  }-*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's doing it without JSNI or DOM:
This grid updates contents of the second span header with dynamic content when datasource is loaded. 
Alternately, you could use "onDraw" instead of "dataArrived", if the contents are  static

```
import com.smartgwt.client.types.Alignment;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Button;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Canvas;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.HeaderSpan;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGrid;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.events.DataArrivedEvent;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.events.DataArrivedHandler;

public class MyGrid extends ListGrid {

    private HeaderSpan          oneHeaderSpan = new HeaderSpan("span one", new String[] { "a", "b", "c" });
    private HeaderSpan          twoHeaderSpan = new HeaderSpan("span two", new String[] { "d", "e", "f" });
    final private static String ONE_SPAN_ID   = "span1";
    final private static String TWO_SPAN_ID   = "span2";

    public MyGrid() {

        setID("MyGrid");
        setHeight100();
        setWidth100();
        setDataSource(MyDS);
        setHeaderSpans(oneHeaderSpan, twoHeaderSpan);
        oneHeaderSpan.setAttribute("spanId", ONE_SPAN_ID);
        twoHeaderSpan.setAttribute("spanId", TWO_SPAN_ID);
        setHeaderHeight(50);

        addDataArrivedHandler(new DataArrivedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onDataArrived(DataArrivedEvent event) {
                Canvas headerSpans = Canvas.getById(getID() + "_headerSpan");
                // getPeers() did not work for IE
                for (Canvas peer : headerSpans.getParentCanvas().getChildren()) {
                    if (peer.getAttribute("spanId") != null && peer.getAttribute("spanId").equals(TWO_SPAN_ID)) {
                        peer.addChild(createHeaderSpanContents(event));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Canvas createHeaderSpanContents(DataArrivedEvent event) {

        // Your favorite Canvas here:
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setLayoutAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
        button.setHeight100();
        button.setWidth100();
        button.setTitle("+");
        return button;
    }
}
```

Using headerSpans.getParentElement().getChildren()) also works if you are on version of smartgwt preceding 4.1d