# SmartGWT databound ListGrid -> DateItem in column title, reload column onChanged

Tags: calendar, datepicker, title, smartgwt, listgrid

My task is : a databound ListGrid with a column. The title of this column should be "Information for {`infoDate` in format DD-MM-YYYY}" + a DateItem (icon picker only) from which users can modify the `infoDate` which is by default the current date. The values in the column change, according to the date chosen.

So, I took an idea from this question [How to add button in HeaderSpan of SmartGWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534554/how-to-add-button-in-headerspan-of-smartgwt) to reach to the code below. Unfortunately there is a problem : the DateItem doesn't seem clickable, it looks just like an image. Besides, I cannot remove the TextField, it is either a text field or 3 selectable option fields.

I suggest that taking the innerHTML doesn’t take the function of the picker itself, as I tried with Calendar, DateChooser and DatePicker and it worked, but the problem there was the view (I need only the calendar icon that will open the DatePicker onClick).

Thank you in advance for any help or idea!

The imports:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Node;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.NodeList;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.DrawEvent;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.DrawHandler;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGrid;
```

The code:

```
ListGrid infoTable = new ListGrid();
infoTable.setShowRecordComponents(true);
infoTable.setShowRecordComponentsByCell(true);        
infoTable.setWidth100();
infoTable.setDataSource(dataSource);
infoTable.setCanEdit(false);
infoTable.setCanCollapseGroup(false);
infoTable.setCanFreezeFields(false);
infoTable.setCanGroupBy(false);
infoTable.setCanMultiSort(false);
infoTable.setCanSort(false);
infoTable.setCanResizeFields(false);
infoTable.setAutoFetchData(false);
infoTable.addDrawHandler(new DrawHandler() { 
    public void onDraw(final DrawEvent event) { 
        for (Element element : DOMUtils.getElementsByTagName("td")) { 

            if (element.getInnerHTML().startsWith("Information for")) { 
                DOMUtils.removeAllChildNodes(element); 

                final DynamicForm cal = new DynamicForm(); 

                final DateItem infoDate = new DateItem(); 
                infoDate.setDefaultValue(new Date());
                infoDate.setTitle(“Information for ”); 
                infoDate.setTitleAlign(Alignment.LEFT); 
                infoDate.setWrapTitle(false); 
                infoDate.setDisplayFormat(DateDisplayFormat.TOEUROPEANSHORTDATE); 
                infoDate.setUseTextField(true); 
                infoDate.setAlign(Alignment.RIGHT); 
                infoDate.addChangedHandler(new ChangedHandler() { 
                    public void onChanged(final ChangedEvent event) { 
                        //fetch new data, according to the date selected); 
                    } 
                }); 

                cal.setFields(infoDate); 

                element.setInnerHTML(cal.getInnerHTML()); 

            } 
        } 

        // fetch data from DataSource class
        infoTable.fetchData(); 
    } 
});
```

And the class DOMUtils:

```
class DOMUtils {
public static void removeAllChildNodes(Element element) {
    NodeList<Node> childList = element.getChildNodes();
    for(int childIndex = 0; childIndex < childList.getLength(); childIndex++) {
        element.removeChild(childList.getItem(childIndex));
    }
}

public static Element[] getElementsByTagName(String tagName)
{
    JavaScriptObject elements = getElementsByTagNameInternal(tagName);
    int length = getArrayLength(elements);
    Element[] result = new Element[length];
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = getArrayElement(elements, i);
    }
    return result;
}

private static native JavaScriptObject getElementsByTagNameInternal(String tagName)/*-{
return $doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
  }-*/;

private static native int getArrayLength(JavaScriptObject array)/*-{
return array.length;
  }-*/;

private static native Element getArrayElement(JavaScriptObject array, int position)/*-{
return (position>=0 && position<array.length?array[position]:null);
  }-*/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, no need for any of this. You can use `setShowFilterEditor(true)` and the default interface for a field of type "date" is going to look just like what you want, except the picker launched from the calendar icon is going to allow the user enter a range of dates, which seems more functional than what you want.

If you don't want to support arbitrary date ranges, use `setFilterEditorType()` to replace the default control with your own, more limited control.

If you don't want two lines of headers (the normal headers plus the filterEditor) just use `setShowHeader(false)`.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your answer. The thing is that only the header need to show a date, the column contains all kind of data (int, String, double etc.). When a date is chosen, I do recalculations according to this date and redraw the column with new data.

Comment: In that case your custom FormItem really has nothing to do with the grid's header or FilterEditor and there's no reason to try to cram it into those components.  You can just put it above the ListGrid instead, or, in 3.1 you can add it to the ListGrid's layout (see ListGrid.gridComponents).

Comment: I use 3.0 and yes, I can add it in a form above the grid, but the problem is that the client wants it into the header... :( I can say that this is not possible, but I have to be sure it's not. Do you really think there's no way to do it like that? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the way to do it : as I can't override the Header itself, I use a HeaderSpan with the height of the Header, in order to have only the HeaderSpan visible. However ATTENTION, it works fine on FF, but it causes errors in other parts of the application in IE. Here is the code; the class DOMUtils can be found in my 1st post:

```
// class MyDataSource extends com.smartgwt.client.data.DataSource
MyDataSource dataSource = MyDataSource.getInstance(); 

final HeaderSpan headerSpanCol1 = new HeaderSpan(); 
headerSpanCol1.setTitle("column 1"); 
headerSpanCol1.setFields(MyDataSource.A); 
headerSpanCol1.setHeight(26); 

final HeaderSpan headerSpanCol2 = new HeaderSpan();
// make sure not to have the same element name
headerSpanCol2.setTitle(“Information for”); 
headerSpanCol2.setFields(MyDataSource.D); 
headerSpanCol2.setHeight(26); 

final HeaderSpan headerSpanCol3 = new HeaderSpan(); 
headerSpanCol3.setTitle("column 2"); 
headerSpanCol3.setFields(MyDataSource.B); 
headerSpanCol3.setHeight(26); 

infoTable = new ListGrid() { 

  @Override 
  protected Canvas createRecordComponent(final ListGridRecord record, final Integer colNum) { 

      final String fieldName = this.getFieldName(colNum); 

    // include some icons that I need in the ListGrid here

  } 
}; 
infoTable.setShowRecordComponents(true); 
infoTable.setShowRecordComponentsByCell(true); 

infoTable.setWidth100();
// make height equal to HeaderSpan’s in order to hide header titles and show only the HeaderSpan
infoTable.setHeaderHeight(26);
infoTable.setDataSource(dataSource); 
infoTable.setCanEdit(false); 
infoTable.setCanCollapseGroup(false); 
infoTable.setCanFreezeFields(false); 
infoTable.setCanGroupBy(false); 
infoTable.setCanMultiSort(false); 
infoTable.setCanSort(false); 
infoTable.setCanAutoFitFields(false); 
infoTable.setCanResizeFields(false); 
infoTable.setCanPickFields(false); 
infoTable.setAutoFetchData(false); 
infoTable.addDrawHandler(new DrawHandler() { 
public void onDraw(final DrawEvent event) { 

   for (Element element : DOMUtils.getElementsByTagName("td")) { 
       // iterate over the elements of the page to find the HeaderSpan to replace

       if (element.getInnerHTML().equals(“Information for”)) { 
          // replace the title of this HeaderSpan with a DateItem 
          DOMUtils.removeAllChildNodes(element); 

          final DynamicForm cal = new DynamicForm(); 

         final DateItem infoDate = new DateItem(); 
         infoDate.setDefaultValue(new Date()); 
         infoDate.setTitle(“Select date”); 
         infoDate.setWrapTitle(false); 
         infoDate.setDisplayFormat(DateDisplayFormat.TOEUROPEANSHORTDATE); 
         infoDate.setUseTextField(true); 
         infoDate.setAlign(Alignment.RIGHT); 
         infoDate.addChangedHandler(new ChangedHandler() { 
             public void onChanged(final ChangedEvent event) { 
                 // reload table with newly fetched results                       
             } 
         }); // ChangedHandler

         cal.setFields(infoDate);
         element.insertFirst(cal.getElement());

 break;
} // if
    } // for


    // fetch data from DataSource class
  infoTable.fetchData(); 
} // onDraw
}); // DrawHandler

infoTable.setHeaderSpans(headerSpanCol1, headerSpanCol2, headerSpanCol3);
```