# change filter icon place in smartGWT

Tags: java, filter, smartgwt, listgrid

is it possible in SmartGWT to change the filter icon place from right to left ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- hide the last filter button
- add a new filter button in the beginning and add your listener to perform filterting

Please have a look at [How to add button in HeaderSpan of SmartGWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534554/how-to-add-button-in-headerspan-of-smartgwt)